# PyAudio. How to record while playing sound

Tags: pyaudio

I used PyAudio for recording and sounding.

Both can work respectively, but I couldn't record while sounding.

It always first sound and record or record and sound.

I tried thread but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [playrec()](http://python-sounddevice.rtfd.org/#sounddevice.playrec) function from http://python-sounddevice.rtfd.org/.

```
import sounddevice as sd
myrecording = sd.playrec(myarray, samplerate, channels=2)
```